# Allow custom tags with dashes in kses filter in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I wrote a small Wordpress plugin which allows adding user defined HTML Custom Element Tags (like `<my-element>`) to the HTML of a Post. So with that a User that doesn't have the capability `unfiltered_html` is at least capable of using such predefined Custom Tags.

The Problem is if I add a filter like so:

```
add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html', 'returnAllowedCustomTags', 10, 2);
function returnAllowedCustomTags($allowedTags, $context) {
    $myAllowedTags = array('my-element' = > array(), 'myelement' = > array());
    $allowedTags = array_merge($allowedTags, $myAllowedTags);
    return $allowedTags;
}
```

Saving html `<myelement>blah</myelement>` is possible. But saving html `<my-element>blah</my-element>` is not possible. I think this is because before filtering the HTML Tags with dashes are removed from HTML string.

Is there a good solution (without adjust wordpress core files) to prevent wordpress kses from filtering html tags with dashes?

And I don't want to give the users the `unfiltered_html` capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after trying several approaches I came up with the following solution:

```
add_filter('wp_kses_allowed_html', 'returnAllowedCustomTags', 10, 2);
// use this filter to replace all custom tags with dashes before kses filter is applied
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'transformCustomTags', 9);
// use this to retransform filtered html before saving
add_filter('content_save_pre', 'retransformCustomTags', 11);

function transformCustomTags($html) {
  $customTags = array('my-element', 'my-element1', 'my-element2');
  // iterate over all allowed custom tags and replace them so they won't get stripped out by kses filter
  foreach ($customTags as $tag) {
    // transform each tag name replacing dash with '0000'
    // e.g. <my-element ...> will be replaced with <my0000element ...>
    // with that we can pevent kses from stripping them out
    $pattern = '<' . $tag;
    $replace = '<' . str_ireplace('-', '0000', $tag);
    $html = str_ireplace($pattern, $replace, $html);
    // replace all closing tags analog to opening tags above
    $pattern = '</' . $tag;
    $replace = '</' . str_ireplace('-', '0000', $tag);
    $html = str_ireplace($pattern, $replace, $html);
  }
  return $html;
}

function retransformCustomTags($html) {
  $customTags = array('my-element', 'my-element1', 'my-element2');
  // iterate over all allowed tags and reverse transformation to get the dash again in tag names
  foreach ($customTags as $tag) {
    // e.g. <my0000element ...> will be replaced with <my-element" ...>
    $pattern = '<' . str_ireplace('-', '0000', $tag);
    $replace = '<' . $tag;
    $html = str_ireplace($pattern, $replace, $html);
    // replace all closing tags analog to opening tags above
    $pattern = '</' . str_ireplace('-', '0000', $tag);
    $replace = '</' . $tag;
    $html = str_ireplace($pattern, $replace, $html);
  }
  return $html;
}

function returnAllowedCustomTags($allowedTags, $context) {
  $myAllowedTags = array('my-element', 'my-element1', 'my-element2');
  foreach ($myAllowedTags as $tag) {
    $tagNameEscaped =  str_ireplace('-', '0000', $tag);
    $allowedTags[$tagNameEscaped] = array();
  }
  return $allowedTags;
}
```

Basically I replace the dash in tag name for any allowed custom tag. `<my-element ...>...</my-element>` is transformed to `<my0000element ...>...</my0000element>`. After that kses filter can do it's work but accepts tag `<my0000element>`. After kses filter is done but before saving `$html` to database I retransform `<my0000element ...>...</my0000element>` back to `<my-element ...>...</my-element>`.

With that solution dashes in tag names won't get strip out for custom tags defined as allowed tags. So users who don't have capability `unfiltered_html` are able to use a predefined set of custom elements.

Of course the replace pattern for dash could be a little safer gegarding false matchings. But for demonstration needs `0000` was enough.

Note: With that approach there is no adjustment in wordpress core code. Only using it's provided hooks.